# PHP mysql header page refresh infinite loop

Tags: php, mysql, header, infinite-loop

I'm trying to refresh a page to update the values in a text box, but I'm getting an infinite loop.

"Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

```
if($POST_['rem1'] != $quantity){
$query = "update cart set quantity=".$_POST['rem1'].";";
mysql_query($query);
header('Location: http://~/cart.php');
```

}

Does anyone have any suggestions on a way to make it execute once, or a better implementation?

Thanks!

Comment: You could add a GET flag, like `cart.php?donotloop=true` and check for that...

Comment: Its $_POST not $POST_ in the if statement

Comment: Wait a second. You directly query an input value? Surely, it's not *that* safe.

Comment: yeah im not concerned much with "proper" coding at this point, I just want to get the stupid thing to work. Thanks for the tip though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That will never get `false`

```
if($POST_['rem1'] != $quantity){
```

hence the page will redirect infinitely.

it should be

```
if($_POST['rem1'] != $quantity){
```